# Complex Types not working in Entity Model 3.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to add a stored procedure to entity model. When I try function import, and want to use a complex type based on SP structure, it doesn't allow me. Infact Complex Types Option is disabled.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Disabled, or doesn't exist? I don't think Entity Framework supported returning complex data types from function imports in .NET 3.5, you could only define a complex data type as a property of an entity.

Comment: Then how can I use stored procedures in 3.5 which return a custom dataset?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. In that version of Entity Framework, you can only return instances of existing entity types from stored procedures. You could create a table or view that matches what you want to return and add it to your entity model, or upgrade to EF 4.0 (or 4.1), which comes with many other added benefits, such as significant improvements to generated SQL and better performance overall.

Comment: hmm .. A big negative point for EF1. This is fixed for Framework 4 though. Creating a view and mapping it to entity model can be a workaround for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way how to solve this issue is upgrading to EF 4.0 because returning complex types from function imports is new feature of EFv4.

Comment: Then how can I use stored procedures in 3.5 which return a custom dataset?

Comment: You can check if [EF Extensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions) for VS 2008 has some support but with standard EFv1 you can't.